# How to keep track of which view is being displayed in a view flipper?

Tags: android, viewflipper

I'm trying to create a custom implementation of ViewFlipper but I'm finding it rather confusing to keep track of which view is being called. I have put a log in my class like below:

```
@Override
public void setDisplayedChild(int childIndex) {
    Log.d("hello", childIndex);
}
```

I added 4 child views to test the class. Now, when showNext() is called things are all fine and the following result occurs: 1; 2; 3; 4; 1; 2... When I call showPrevious() however thing go a bit wrong and the result I get is: -1; 2; 1; 0; -1; 2...

Why do the sequences start and end with different numbers?

Comment: You need to provide way more code than that.

Answer (score 1):

[`ViewFlipper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) inherits from `ViewAnimator`:

[getCurrentView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#getCurrentView%28%29) : Returns the View corresponding to the currently displayed child.

[getDisplayedChild()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#getDisplayedChild%28%29) : Returns the index of the currently displayed child view.

Also, before setting the child index, check if it is valid.

Comment: That is the thing. I'm not calling this method. I'm only calling showNext and showPrevious and this is the index I get.